# Error in the most recent version of komacv

Tags: komacv

In the most recent version I stumbled upon a small error that is maybe not so hard to fix, but I am unable to do it.

When setting the option `style=casual`

This gets passed down to (I think) hyperref and hence bookmark, which then reports an error that casual is not a valid style.
The exact error message is

```
Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty:619 Package bookmark Error: Undefined style `casual’.
```

(running MacTeX2019 with all packages up to date)

For now I only solved it by copying your komacv.cls into my CV-folder and setting the default to casual, then it does not get passed down to `bookmark`.

How can I fix this error in the class itself (i.e. avoiding passing down style)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the error like this:

```
\documentclass[style=casual]{komacv}
 \makeatletter\providecommand\BKM@style@casual{}\makeatother
 \usepackage{bookmark}
 \begin{document}
 blblb
 \end{document}
```

It is imho an error from bookmark to fail over such document options. There is an open issue for it: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/67. The code will be changed soon (actually I thought I had already done it ;-().

Comment: neat! Thanks for the info. That fixes my CV for the moment :)